# Deploy angular 9 app to heroku - deploy success but not work

Tags: angular, heroku

**Answer**:

I didnt have in package.json

```
"express":"^4.17.1",

"body-parser":"^1.19.0"
```

in the dependencies

//////////////////////////////////////////

I tried to deploy my angular 9 app to heroku

1. I Added my server.js file to root dir
2. I changed "start" to "node server.js"

the app had compiled successfully but get that massage :
"Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command"

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "student-to-mentor-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.1",
    "@material/dialog": "^5.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.3",
    "npm": "6.4.1"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./dist/MentorToStudent_Client'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./dist/MentorToStudent_Client/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

**heroku log**

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  10.15.3
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.4.1

       Resolving node version 10.15.3...
       Downloading and installing node 10.15.3...
       npm 6.4.1 already installed with node

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       audited 15663 packages in 13.701s
       found 2 low severity vulnerabilities
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

-----> Build
       Running build

       > student-to-mentor-client@0.0.0 build /tmp/build_36d2d6939d3ac760e14a5ab5486fc99d
       > ng build

       Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
       ES5 bundle generation complete.

       chunk {runtime} runtime-es2015.js, runtime-es2015.js.map (runtime) 6.16 kB [entry] [rendered]
       chunk {runtime} runtime-es5.js, runtime-es5.js.map (runtime) 6.16 kB [entry] [rendered]
       chunk {styles} styles-es2015.js, styles-es2015.js.map (styles) 9.73 kB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {styles} styles-es5.js, styles-es5.js.map (styles) 11 kB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {main} main-es2015.js, main-es2015.js.map (main) 240 kB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {main} main-es5.js, main-es5.js.map (main) 265 kB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es2015.js, polyfills-es2015.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 656 kB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {vendor} vendor-es2015.js, vendor-es2015.js.map (vendor) 3.72 MB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {vendor} vendor-es5.js, vendor-es5.js.map (vendor) 4.39 MB [initial] [rendered]
       Date: 2020-04-17T12:01:03.501Z - Hash: a3c1c0e77ff01fc0442e - Time: 48701ms
WARNING in ./src/app/register/register.component.css
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Warning
(69:4) Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like `to left` instead of `right`.

-----> Caching build
       - node_modules

-----> Pruning devDependencies
       removed 975 packages and audited 3092 packages in 14.344s
       found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 72.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v6
```

I hope someone can help or get a suggestion what can be the problem???.

even localhost 8080 is work (node server.js - command)

Comment: add this script `"postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"` and then try again.

Comment: I tried - not work..

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `heroku logs` to see what kind of error it throws.